# cannot click UIButton on custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, user-interaction

I have a custom view, for example `ParentView` : `UIView`. Inside this view I have one `UIButton` that I'm adding programatically as

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
    [self addSubview:btn];
```

and the action:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"button pressed: %@",sender);
}
```

In my storyboard I have a basic View, whose class I've set to ParentView. The initialization is indeed called, and the UIButton is created fine, just the action is not called. The ParentView has `userInterActionEnabled` checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UIControlEventTouchUpInside event instead of UIControlEventTouchUpOutside.